# XML Serialization - Required attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class that should represent a controller's action parameter and I'd like its properties to be "required" (meaning, you get a status code 400 or something in case it's passed as null). I managed to get it done using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, but the ErrorMessage that I pass to the constructor of the `Required` attribute is never shown.

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
    public class Request
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "prop")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The property is required.")]
        public string Property { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(ElementName = "another")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The property is required.")]
        public string Another { get; set; }
    }
```

Action:

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Request value)
        {
            return Ok(value); //ignore this, it's just for testing purposes...
        }
```

However, if I don't pass the Property value, I get a 400 that doesn't contain the ErrorMessage I passed earlier. Am I missing something here?

```xml
<ValidationProblemDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Title>One or more validation errors occurred.</Title>
    <Status>400</Status>
</ValidationProblemDetails>
```

My Startup has Xml formatters added to it:

```cs
    services.AddMvc(options => 
    {
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;

        options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlSerializerInputFormatter(options));
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

The body of the request looks like this, and it doesn't have "Property":

```xml
<root>
    <another>Test</another>
    <!-- Property "Property" is missing here -->
</root>
```

Comment: How have you configured the startup to support XML? Can you share the request that you are making?

Comment: @joacoleza I edited my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Code Rethinked for the huge help - [Customizing automatic HTTP 400 error response in ASP.NET Core Web APIs](https://coderethinked.com/customizing-automatic-http-400-error-response-in-asp-net-core-web-apis/).

An approach that I managed to figure out eventually includes the use of `services.Configure` in my `Startup.ConfigureServices` method.

```cs
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
    {
        return new OkObjectResult(new CustomResponse(someStatusCode, context))
        {
            ContentTypes = { "application/xml" }
        };
    };
});
```

So, I made a `class` named CustomResponse that holds the status code I want to retrieve and all the validation errors (including the ones where my `Required` property was not passed to the API).

```cs
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "rcemsTrxSubReqAck")]
    public class CustomResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [XmlArray(ElementName = "Errors"), XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Error")]
        public string[] Errors { get; set; }

        public CustomResponse(int status, ActionContext context)
        {
            Status = status;
            Errors = ConstructErrorMessages(context);
        }

        private string[] ConstructErrorMessages(ActionContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            string[] arr = new string[context.ModelState.ErrorCount];

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var keyModelStatePair in context.ModelState)
            {
                var key = keyModelStatePair.Key;
                var errors = keyModelStatePair.Value.Errors;
                if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (errors.Count == 1)
                    {
                        var errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(errors[0]);
                        arr[i] = $"{key}: {errorMessage}";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var errorMessages = new string[errors.Count];
                        for (var j = 0; j < errors.Count; j++)
                        {
                            errorMessages[j] = GetErrorMessage(errors[j]);
                        }

                        arr[i] = $"{key}: {errorMessages.ToString()}";
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }

            return arr;
        }

        private string GetErrorMessage(ModelError error)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(error.ErrorMessage) ? "The input was not valid." : error.ErrorMessage;
        }
    }
```